# Trim URL by variable

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

Hi I have a Link like this:

```
mypage.php?product=3&page=1
```

I want to delete the &page=1, &page=2, &page=5 and so.
I have tried this, but I think it is not right.

```
str_replace('/(\\?|&)page=.*?(&|$)/', '', $link);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace()` doesn't work with regular expressions, so you'd use `preg_replace()` instead:

```
$url = preg_replace('/[?&]page=[^&]+/', '', $url);
```

Two changes here: first, it's better to use a character class instead of alternation when you target individual symbol only (not having to escape `?` within the brackets is a nice bonus), second, `[^&]+` ('match any number of non-& characters') construct is more direct and readable than `.+?(&|$)` one.